# Retain privileges when dropping objects in Oracle

Tags: oracle, ddl, privileges, sql-grant

It occurred to me that I have a fundamental issue with respect to privileges.. Anyone who is granted access to my data warehouse, will be given privileges to objects in the reporting schema. However, whenever we drop objects, those privileges are lost.

The fundamental requirements that should be met with the approach are:

1. Indexes not populated during load of data (dropped, disabled?) to avoid populating while inserting
2. Retain existing privileges.

What do you guys think is the best approach based on the requirements above?

Comment: alter over drop-recreate.

Comment: Alternatively, keep all GRANT statements in a single .SQL file. Run it once everything is created.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda How to do so? Can you please show an example.

Comment: @Littlefoot Privileges must be retained. Meaning they shouldn't be lost even if I drop all objects.

Comment: Do you understand what you are saying? You have a table. You granted SELECT on that table to me. Then you drop the table. How & why should Oracle keep information about the fact that you, once upon a time, granted anything to me on a **dropped object**? That just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Littlefoot Its a part of a (dropping & re-creating) procedure which will drop all tables and re-create and while doing that it should retain privileges somehow.

Comment: That's a nice make-a-wish. Unfortunately, it won't be fulfilled.

Comment: You have a procedure that drops all tables and recreates them? That should not be part of any business process, and even if it is, surely the procedure should finish the job by reapplying any grants. Or, if this is part of a build process, that process should manage grants.

Comment: You could use grants on views. You can drop the underlying tables (which makes the views invalid) but when the tables are recreated the views can be recompiled to make them valid and the grants would still be present.

Comment: @Littlefoot: to be fair, in some DBMS (e.g. Postgres) you can define _default_ privileges on a schema that apply automatically to all objects created in the future. I guess that's what samg is looking for, but Oracle can't do that.

Comment: @samg: as Littlefoot pointed out: you need to store the GRANTs you have in a SQL script and then run them as part of the script that populates the database. That's the correct way to do this in Oracle

Comment: Don't drop an object if you're about to re-create it. Instead, **`alter`** the object - that way grants are retained.

Answer (score 3):

For requirement 1: depending on the version of Oracle you're running, you may be able to alter the indexes as invisible. Making indexes invisible will cause the optimizer to ignore them, but it can come in handy because you can simply make them visible again after whatever operation you're performing. If that won't work, you could alter them unusable instead. More info here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/invisible-indexes-11gr1

For requirement 2: Once an object is dropped, the privileges are dropped along with it. There's not really any straightforward way to retain the grants ***as they are*** when an object is dropped, however, you could use a number of different methods to "save" the privileges when a table is dropped. These are just some ideas to get you going, not a guaranteed method of success.

- Method 1: Using Triggers and DBMS_SCHEDULER to issue the grants. Triggers can be very powerful, and if you create a trigger that is set to run when a table of a specific name is created under a specific schema, you can use DBMS_SCHEDULER to run a job that will issue the missing grants.
- Method 2: Per Littlefoot's suggestion, you can save the grant statements in a SQL script and run it manually every time the table is created (or create a trigger for it!)
- Method 3: Work with the business and implement a process wherein the table does not need to be dropped, and instead is altered to fit business needs. To use this method, you'll have to understand why the object is being dropped in the first place. Is a drop really necessary to accomplish the desired outcome? I've seen teams request that tables be dropped when they really just wanted the tables to be truncated. If this is one of those scenarios, truncating instead of dropping will let you keep the object and its grants intact.

In any scenario, you'll also want to make sure that you are managing permissions via roles whenever possible, rather than issuing grants to individual users/schemas. Utilizing roles will make managing permissions a lot easier in just about any scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you `DROP` an object, the grants are gone.  However:

> ```
> Indexes not populated during load of data (dropped, disabled?) to avoid
>     populating while inserting
> Retain existing privileges.
> ```

Here is one common approach.  There are others.  If you have partitioning there are better ways.

```
ALTER INDEX my_index1 UNUSABLE;
ALTER INDEX my_index2 UNUSABLE;
...
ALTER INDEX my_indexn UNUSABLE;
TRUNCATE TABLE my_table_with_n_indexes;  -- OPTIONAL (depends if you need to start empty)
INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO my_table_with_n_indexes;  -- Do your load here.  APPEND hint optional, depending on what you are doing
ALTER INDEX my_index1 REBUILD;
ALTER INDEX my_index2 REBUILD;
...
ALTER INDEX my_indexn REBUILD;
```